# How to count the number of times elements in one array appears in another

Tags: c, arrays, loops

newb beginner here. I am trying to understand how to loop between two arrays (words, and uniques) so I can find out how many times each element in uniques array appears in the words array.
Here is my non-working code, please can someone help me see where I am messing up the loops?

Thanks!

```
#define MAXWORDS 100
#define ALLWORDS 1000

int main()
{

int c, state, nowords;
state = OUT;

int array[MAXWORDS] = {0};
char words[ALLWORDS] = {'0'};


 for (int i = 0; i < MAXWORDS; ++i)
    /* printf("%i", array[i]) */; 
/* printf("\n"); */ 

/* Filling an array correctly!!! */
int count;
count = 0;
int countchars;
countchars = 0;
while((c = getchar())!= EOF)
{
    words[countchars++] = c;
    count++;

    switch(c) {
        case ' ':
        case '\n':
        case '\t':
            if(state == IN)
            {
                state = OUT;
                ++nowords;
            }
            count = 0;
            break;
        default:
            state = IN;
            if(count > 0)
                array[nowords] = count;
            break;
    }
}

words[countchars + 1] = '\0'; 

printf("number of chars in each word in the sentence: ");
for (int i = 0; array[i] != 0; i++)
    printf("%i,", array[i]);
printf("\n");

printf("What was typed and stored into the words array: ");
for(int k = 0; words[k] != '\0'; k++)
    printf("%c", words[k]);
printf("\n");

printf("Finding unique chars: ");
int a, b;
char uniques[ALLWORDS] = {'0'};

for(a = 0; a < countchars; a++)
{
    for(b = 0; b < a; b++)
    {
        if(words[a] == words[b])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(a == b)
    {
        uniques[a] = words[a];
    }
}

uniques[a + 1] = '\0';

for(int d = 0; d != ALLWORDS; d++)
    printf("%c", uniques[d]);
printf("\n");

int counting = 0;
for(int j = 0; j < countchars; j++)
{
    counting = 0;
    for(int h = 0; h < a; h++)
    {
        if(words[h] == uniques[j])
            ++counting;
    }
    printf("\"%c\": %i ", uniques[j], counting);
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

I'm getting output like this which is kind of weird:

```
 ./homework
a big fat herd of kittens
number of chars in each word in the sentence: 1,3,3,4,2,7,
What was typed and stored into the words array: a big fat herd of kittens

Finding unique chars: a bigftherdokns

"a": 2 
" ": 5 
"b": 1 
"i": 2 
"g": 1 
"": 0 
"f": 2 
"": 0 
"t": 3 
"": 0 
"h": 1 
"e": 2 
"r": 1 
"d": 1 
"": 0 
"o": 1 
"": 0 
"": 0 
"k": 1 
"": 0 
"": 0 
"": 0 
"": 0 
"n": 1 
"s": 1 
"
": 1
```

Comment: What is `countchars` and `a`

Comment: How is 'a' initialized - hopefully as 'strlen(words);'?

Comment: Sorry. countchars and a  are variables used to count the length of the arrays. words is collected from user input, uniques is gotten from counting the unique elements in words. Sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way of doing this is the following:
use a third array: char counts[5] ( must have same size as your uniques array )
counts[0] would hold the number of times letter 'a' appears in the "words" array, counts[1] would hold the number of times letter 'b' appears in the "words" array, and so on...

Therefore you will only need a single for loop where you do the following:
check if words[i] is in the uniques array ( basically you check if words[i] <= 'e' ). If words[i] is indeed <= 'e' then you will increment counts[words[i] - 'a'].

Now let's see how that "words[i]-'a'" actually works.
if words[i] is 'a' then you would have words[i] - 'a' = 'a' - 'a' = 0 ( first position in counts array)
if words[i] is 'b' then you would have words[i] - 'a' = 'b' - 'a' = 1 ( second position in counts array).

You use the inefficient approach with 2 for loops.

Also, a good way of finding bugs, especially in small code like this, is to actually take a piece of paper and a pen, and try to follow how to code works on small input. Another ( and more efficient way ) would be step by step debugging and actually seeing what value each variable holds.

Hope I was clear enough. Good luck :D